# Flutter search listview item

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, search

This is search address from cutnumid to show listview showing all address done and how can I want to search by typing only part of address? I've tried many different things and always crashes. please help me

```
//search custnum showaddress
 onSearch(String text) async {
if (text.isNotEmpty) {
  List<Item> itemList = [];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (item.custnum == text.toLowerCase().toUpperCase()) {
      itemList.add(item);
      setState(() {
        searchitems.clear();
        searchitems.addAll(itemList);
        print('name : ${searchitems[0].name}');
        if (searchitems.isEmpty) {
          searchitems = [];
          // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!.length}');
          // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!}');
        }
      });
    }
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    searchitems.clear();

    // searchitems.addAll(items);
    print('searchitems : $searchitems');
  });
}
```

}

This is the code to search only for the words typed into the textfield. to display only searched This section may be invalid code. I gave an example.

```
    onSearchAddr(String text) async {
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    searchitems[0].address!.forEach((f) {
      if (f.addr1.toString().toLowerCase().contains(text))
        items.add(searchitems[0]);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You `setState()` on every single iteration. What if the iteration is faster than `build` method? it will crash, cause the app has to be redrawn when it is still redrawing.

naive way to search by part of string. use `contains` method of `String`.

```js
 onSearch(String text) async {
if (text.isNotEmpty) {
  List<Item> itemList = [];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (item.custnum.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
      itemList.add(item);
      
    }
  }
  setState(() {
        searchitems.clear();
        searchitems.addAll(itemList);
        print('name : ${searchitems[0].name}');
      });
} else {
  setState(() {
    searchitems.clear();

    // searchitems.addAll(items);
    print('searchitems : $searchitems');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code seems to be working.

It could be errors from elsewhere such as unbounded `ListView`

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

enum Item { one, two, three, four, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR }

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  //search custnum showaddress
  List<Item> searchitems = [Item.ONE];
  List<Item> items = Item.values;
  onSearch(String text) async {
    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      List<Item> itemList = [];
      for (var item in items) {
        if (item.name.toLowerCase() == text) {
          itemList.add(item);
          setState(() {
            searchitems.clear();
            searchitems.addAll(itemList);
            print('name : ${searchitems[0].name}');
            if (searchitems.isEmpty) {
              searchitems = [];
              // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!.length}');
              // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!}');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        searchitems.clear();

        // searchitems.addAll(items);
        print('searchitems : $searchitems');
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          onSubmitted: onSearch,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: searchitems.map((e) => Text(e.name)).toList(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```